# jQuery Loop JSON Result with Object as Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have this format of JSON output but I could not figure out how to check the key and the value. Here is my JSON output:

```
[
    {"msgone":
        {"msgId":"1",
        "custName":"MYCUST"}
    },
    {"msgtwo":
        {"msgId":"2",
        "custName":"MYCUST"}
    },
    {"msgtwo":
        {"msgId":"2",
        "custName":"MYCUST"}
    }
]
```

There you go. Now what I want to do is first I want to loop each of them and check if it is `msgone` then do something. If it is `msgtwo` then do something. If let's say current loop is `msgone` then I want to take all the object `msgId` and `custName` to do further processing.

This is part of the code that I have at this moment:

```
success: function(msg){
    $('#res').val(msg); //just echo to debug
    var returnedRep = $.parseJSON(msg);
    $.each(returnedRep, function(index, value) {
        if(returnedRep[index] === 'msgone'){
            //give me the values
        }
        if(returnedRep[index] === 'msgtwo'){
            //give me the values
        }
    });
}
```

Appreciate your feedback on this. I am new to JSON. But with different form of it, I could not able how to read through it. Thank you.

---

UPDATE:
This is how I code that outputs my JSON data:

```
$globArr [] = array(
    "type" => "msgone",
    "data" => array(
        "msgId" => $details[0], 
        "custName" => $details[1]
    )
);
```

Each time the message comes, I will store them in `$globArr`. I could not figure out how to make structure like @DemoUser suggested. Anybody please help me.

Comment: Can you control the JSON?

Comment: @vol7ron yes I can control it.

Comment: To me that's an odd way of storing the object, though there are reasons why creating an array of hashes, is useful, in this case you could do a hash of array of hashes: `{ msgone: [{..}],  msgtwo: [{msgId:'2',custName:'MYCUST'}, {…}]}`

Comment: @vol7ron I guess your suggestion is same with the answer below. I will give it a shot

Comment: Yes @DemoUser came to the same conclusion, but made your hash even more uniform, giving it some additional structure, which isn't a bad idea.  How much structure you want to give it depends on how much space you want to save (how big your object is), who is reading it, and how descriptive you want your object to be.  There isn't too much more markup there, which would make it easier to maintain in the future.

Comment: @vol7ron thanks for the explanation, actually the data is pretty big,I just put it a little bit because I don't want to copy and paste too  much thing here plus the structures are all same. will try it first later :)

Comment: Keep in mind that arrays preserve order, so if the order of the messages matter, then maybe your original format was fine, otherwise you'd need to capture that metadata as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create the json data by yourself, then you could make the data consistent, something like:

```
[
    {
        "type": "msgone",
        "data" : [
            {
                "msgId":"1",
                "custName":"MYCUST"
            }
         ]
    },
    {
        "type" : "msgtwo",
        "data" : [
            {
                "msgId":"2",
                "custName":"MYCUST"
            },
            {
                "msgId":"2",
                "custName":"MYCUSTSOME"
            },
        ]
    }
]
```

and you could parse it as:

```
success: function(msg){
    $('#res').val(msg); //just echo to debug
    var returnedRep = $.parseJSON(msg);
    $.each(returnedRep, function(key, val) {
        var type = val.type;
        var dataArr = val.data;
        $.each(dataArr, function(idx, v) {
            alert(v.msgId);
        });
    });
}
```

Update for json structure in PHP:: (this gives you the required format like i mentioned),

```
$arr = array();
$arr[] = array(
    "type" => "msgOne",
    "data" => array(
        array("msgId" => 1, "custName" => "Some name")
    )
);
$arr[] = array(
    "type" => "msgTwo",
    "data" => array(
        array("msgId" => 2, "custName" => "Some second name"),
        array("msgId" => 3, "custName" => "Some third name"),
    )
);
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Comment: thank you for the response. I will give this one a try and let you know the result as I will need some time to populate the JSON :)

Comment: I am not able to produce the JSON output like you suggested. Could you please help me? I updated the question.

Comment: @UserProg see my updated answer, i've added an example of the way to add data to array and json_encode() it to output the required format, you'll have to pass in your values to PHP array in the format specified as in above example and it should work fine